# matching table tag by regular expression in php

Tags: regex

I need to match a substring in php substring is like

```
<table class="tdicerik" id="dgVeriler"
```

I wrote a regular expression to it like `<table\s*\sid=\"dgVeriler\"` but it didnot work where is my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a dot:

```
<table\s.*\sid="dgVeriler"
```

would have worked.

```
<table\s+.*?\s+id="dgVeriler"
```

would have been better (making the repetition lazy, matching as little as possible).

```
<table\s+[^>]*?\s+id="dgVeriler"
```

would have been better still (making sure that we don't accidentally match outside of the `<table>`tag).

And not trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, using a parser instead, would probably have been best.

Comment: A simple DOM `getElementById()` or perhaps an XPath `//table[@id='dgVeriler']` would be preferable indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want get but try this:

```
<table\s*.*id=\"dgVeriler\"
```

Comment: Doesn't work if there is, somewhere after, the string `id="dgVeriler"`. You should make your regex ungreedy by adding `?` after the `.*` like `.*?`.

Comment: sure, after adding something else, but for <table class="tdicerik" id="dgVeriler", should be ok. Author dont mention what he want :) only say "match", so.. this regex match to his string.